# Filling a 2D Array (a Matrix)

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

Consider, for instance, the following formula:

$$f_{nm}(x) = \sin(n \ m \ x^2/\pi)$$

where $n$ and $m$ both are integers $\in [1,4]$. Forming a **matrix** with this information would result in:

$$\mathbf{F} =  \begin{pmatrix}\ f_{11} & f_{12} & f_{13} & f_{14} \\ f_{21} & f_{22} & f_{23} & f_{24} \\ f_{31} & f_{32} & f_{33} & f_{34} \\ f_{41} &f_{42}&f_{43}&f_{44}\end{pmatrix}$$

How to create such a $4\times4$ matrix in **Python** and fill it with the provided formula for a given $x$ please. I know this question may be off-topic here, but the $LaTeX$ style of the equations did not work for me in the StackOverflow, that is why posted it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed $x$ you should be able to do this

```
import numpy as np

f = np.zeros((4,4))
for n in range(4):
    for m in range(4):
        f[n][m] = np.sin(n*m*(x**2)/np.pi)
```

Comment: Dear @Zebx could you help me with the following code:  `import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import linalg


x = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5)
f = np.zeros((4,4))
for n in range(4):
    for m in range(4):
        f[n][m] = np.sin(n*m*(x**2)/np.pi)
E = linalg.eigvals(f)
plt.plot(x, E)
plt.show` It gives the following error: **setting an array element with a sequence.**

Comment: @Sha I don't remember properly python language, but from the code you shown it seems you want to estimate the eigenvalues of different f matrices, created with different x values. You can't plot x vs E, cause x is a single value while E is a vector. You can't even create a vector with all the x values you used and plot it vs E because E is related to a specific matrix, so to a specific x. Unless I didn't understand something, that should be the problem.

Comment: @Sha I suggest you to ask a new question on StackOverflow if you can't resolve the problem. In this case you don't need to use latex, and you can eventually link to your new question this question for details.

Comment: Yes actually I am trying to find eigenvalues and plot them versus position coordinates. The problem is that there exists such a plot (knowing it from the accompanied answer to the prblem I am trying to understand myself). I may even post this code in a later time. Thank you very much you already helped me a lot by shwoing me how to populate a matrix with a given formula.

Answer (score 0):

A faster implementation avoiding Python loops (if I understood your question correctly) that assumes that also `x` is an array from 0 to 1 and exploits [Numpy Broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

```
import numpy as np

n = np.arange(1, 5)
m = n.reshape(4, 1)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100).reshape(100, 1, 1)

result = np.sin(n * m * x**2 / np.pi)

print(result.shape)
```

This gives a result array of dimensions:

```
(100, 4, 4)
```

where the first dimensions indexes the `x` value. That is:

```
result[0, ...]
```

is the 4x4 matrix corresponding to `x = x[0] = 0`